# chain logical AND without fixed length given an array in Node.js and Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, object

Scenario:

I am making a generic function that returns a boolean depending on logical AND statements, however, the function being generic accept multiple type of objects and arrays, and the  statements can vary depending on the objects.

at the moment I have something like this

```
private async myFunction( 
    myArray: myArrObj[],
    myObj : myObj,
  ): Promise<boolean> {

    return (
      myArr.some(
        (a) =>
          a.status1=== "*" ||
          a.status1 === myObj.status1.status1Id
      ) &&
      myArr.some( 
        (a) =>
          a.status2=== "*" ||
          a.status2 === myObj.status2.status2Id
      ) &&
      myArr.some(
        (a) =>
          a.status3=== "*" ||
          a.status3 === myObj.status3.status3Id
      ) &&
     myArr.some(
        (a) =>
          a.status4=== "*" ||
          a.status4 === myObj.status4.status4Id
      ) 
    )
  }
```

the issue is not being able to know what kind of array is passed and how many checks are needed, how can I make a return? My idea was storing each array.some method in an array and join them with " && ", this approach would require to execute something from a string, which I'm not sure is the most secure thing to do, since eval is not secure at all.

to get the myObj statuses I could just use a for loop and store the the the property in a string.
I can't come up with a good solution, so feel free to propose something new if my idea is not good enough

Comment: The conditions are the same for all properties? It's just the property name that varies? Or what? It would help to see some examples of the arrays and objects you'll be passing to this function.

Comment: Separately: Properties with names like `status1` / `objStatus1` / `status1Id` are highly suspect. That should probably be an array of `statuses` (in the objects in `myArr`) and status objects with an `id` property (in `myObj`).

Comment: @Yoshi - Not quite. The above just requires that one element in the array matches each of the conditions (it doesn't have to be the same element). `every` would require that *every* element match the series of conditions.

Comment: Regardless, doing multiple loops through `myArr` seems unnecessarily inefficient. A single `for...of` loop and flags for satisfied conditions would let you loop once (at most) and allow you to stop looping once all conditions have been met (even if that's near the beginning of the array).

Comment: please share reproducible example. Try to use predicate function as custom typeguard in typescript it helps to narrow the types.

Comment: I believe you should use some hashmap for already checked values

Comment: maybe I made too much of a simplistic example, but the statuses and id's have different names, some id's are .nameId, and some are just .id , but the statuses themselves have the same name, so  instead of status1 and obStatus1 it really should be status1 and status1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by others in the comments, it would help if you had a reproducible example with sample data. That being said, from your comment:

> but the statuses and id's have different names, some id's are .nameId, and some are just .id , but the statuses themselves have the same name, so instead of status1 and obStatus1 it really should be status1 and status1

Breaking this down:

> but the statuses and id's have different names, some id's are .nameId, and some are just .id

You could try to see if `nameId` exists and fall back to `id`.

> but the statuses themselves have the same name, so instead of status1 and obStatus1 it really should be status1 and status1

When `myArr` entries share keys with `myObj`, then you could simply loop through `myObj`'s keys.

```js
async function myFunction(myArr, myObj) {
    // Fallback value for if .nameId and .id both don't exist.
    // Falling back to `undefined` would cause a bug / false positives.
    const notFound = Symbol();

    // Loop through every key:value pair in the input object.
    return Object.entries(myObj).every(([myObjKey, myObjValue]) => {
        // Handle both `.nameId` and `.id`
        const id = myObjValue[`${myObjKey}Id`] ?? myObjValue.id ?? notFound;

        // If `myArrObj`'s children only ever contain exactly
        // a single key { status2: { someRandomKey: 123 } }, then you
        // could use myObjValue[Object.keys(myObjValue)[0]];

        // For this key--for example "status1"--is there *any* array entry
        // in `myArrObj` that has the same key and value or "*"?
        return myArr.some((a) => {
            return a[myObjKey] === '*' || a[myObjKey] === id;
        });

    }); 
}
```

With the following sample data:

```js
const sampleArr = [
    { status3: "*" },
    { status2: 234 },
    { status1: 123, thisIsAnUnusedKey: true },
    { status4: 456 },
    { name: "Foobar" },
    { thisIsAnUnusedArrayEntry: true },
];
const sampleObj = {
    status1: {
        status1Id: 123,
    },
    status2: {
        status2Id: 234,
    },
    status3: {
        status3Id: 345,
    },
    status4: {
        // Different key
        id: 456,
    },
    name: {
        // Different dataType
        nameId: "Foobar"
    }
};

myFunction(sampleArr, sampleObj).then(console.log); // Logs `true`
```